# Oracle connection unable to connect with SID defined

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames

I have a single database instance and I'm able to connect to it by just using the user and password as such:
sqlplus system/password

However if I try to add an SID to the connection I get the following error:

```
sqlplus system@db1/password

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

I tried to enter a different incorrect SID to check if I get the same error but I get another error:

```
sqlplus system@wrongdb/password

ORA-12514: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I've used the netcfa to create the listener and the service entry is present in the TNSNAMES.ora file. What is preventing the connection with SID?

EDIT: I'm also able to tnsping the service:

```
tnsping SCDEMO
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhos t)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = SCDEMO))) 
OK (0 msec)
```

Comment: If `tnsping SCDEMO` works, your call must be `sqlplus system/password@SCDEMO`. Or is it just an example?

Comment: When you specify `@db1` you don't specify a SID, you specify a TNS name. So there must be an entry `db1` in your `tnsnames.ora`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, it must be

```
sqlplus system/password@db1
```